# 404 Template customization | Want 10 recent Post on the 404.php error page apart from the error Notice

Tags: loop, templates, get-posts

I have created a 404 error template. whose main portion looks like this →

```
    <div class="main col <?php post_class(); ?>">
        <h2>Sorry Boss! This Page doesn't exist.</h2>            
    </div>
```

And the above works quite well. [see here a page that doesn't exist.](http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/ff)

Apart from this error notice I was trying to show top 10 recent posts. so I was trying use the WP Loop →

```
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); >
        <?php get_template_part('content','home'); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

perhaps there should be some other way to achieve this, but I want that this template should be used →

`<?php get_template_part('content','home'); ?>`

so that I can get 10 posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Loop just outputs what is contained in the Main Query, it doesn't fetch any posts on its own. The Main Query is empty on a 404, so there's nothing for The Loop to output.

If you want additional content, you have to query for it yourself:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 10) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    get_template_part('content','home');
endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: Thanks, sir. I am a beginner, and this was enlightening for me.